# Why Haskell typeclasses in Agda are started with `Raw`?

Tags: agda

In the Agda standard library, we have `RawMonad`, `RawApplicative`, etc..

```
RawMonad : ∀ {f} → (Set f → Set f) → Set _
RawMonad M = RawIMonad {I = ⊤} (λ _ _ → M)

RawMonadZero : ∀ {f} → (Set f → Set f) → Set _
RawMonadZero M = RawIMonadZero {I = ⊤} (λ _ _ → M)

RawMonadPlus : ∀ {f} → (Set f → Set f) → Set _
RawMonadPlus M = RawIMonadPlus {I = ⊤} (λ _ _ → M)
```

Why do they start with `Raw`? Are there `Monad` or `Applicative` in Agda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been told by Nils Anders Danielsson (their author, I suspect) once that it's because they don't contain proofs of the respective laws.
AFAIK, the Agda standard library doesn't have versions of these that do contain such proofs, but you can roll your own if you like.

Comment: Why don't they put an implementation in the stdlib? Is that because there're many different ways of proves?

Comment: Also, thanks for your answer. I've reached the daily vote limit and I'll vote your answer tomorrow.

Comment: @ice1000 Because it's not clear which notion of equality should be used.